# StrawberryShake and receiving data from graphql with brotli compression

Tags: graphql, brotli, strawberryshake

I try to connect in a c# application with Strawberryshake a graphql server that compress the response
when there is a lot of data to return.

With small responses there is no problem, i receive json with my answers on my graphql query

But with big response, there is a brotli compression and StrawberryShake goes in error because there is no json returned.

How is it possible tot handle qraphql queries with brottli compression and StrawberryShake ?

I'm on the version of 12.15 of StrawberryShake

Thanks

Nico